# SSH-Keygen -i Fails: uudecode failed. What can cause this?

Tags: ssh

```
root@etoorlan4c:~/.ssh# ssh-keygen -i
Enter file in which the key is (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): 
uudecode failed.
```

I'm trying to get the public key that corresponds to the private key in id_rsa. I run the above command and it fails with a uudecode error. The key is copied and pasted so it's presumably correct. I've tried to use a system generated key `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and that returns an error as well.

```
root@etoorlan4c:~/.ssh# ssh-keygen -i 
Enter file in which the key is (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): 
decode blob failed: invalid format
```

Note, the second example is just to illustrate failure of the command in multiple contexts in case case this is a symptom of a larger error. My main concern is fixing the first error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/root/.ssh/id_rsa` content is invalid, despite you having pasted contents over.

Remove the old file and recreate

```
rm /root/.ssh/id_rsa*
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Comment: If i've copied and pasted the private key into id_rsa, does this imply the key is invalid? It has the standard format including the BEGIN/END lines..

Comment: unbelievable..there was 1 letter missing from the key I had been Copy/Pasting which began after the ----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- header. I don't know how the header made it and the one character was lost afterwards. A painful 12+ hour lesson. Thanks.

Comment: @user1800340 I had a similar problem: There was an unprintable character at the begining of the file. I noticed it when doing `cat` on a provided key file and editors did not show it. So ... if you have the same problem maybe check for missing or invisible chars or BOMs.

Comment: Thank you for saving me the hassle of your 12+ hour ordeal. I recopied from the source and this worked after getting the same initial error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at the `-m` option to specify the format. Besides that, did you copy the key correctly from the provided key, look for newlines and other fancy characters using `vim` and option `:set list`. Perhaps there are characters copied which are not visible and/or the format of the sent key is not the default expected.